# I need help with finding lim

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-3}{x-1}=2$, find $\lim_{x\to1}{f(x)}$.

not sure what to do here. The answers are either $3, 2, 1$ or does not exist. How do I figure this out?

Thx, 
Kevin

Comment: @DanielR, Thank you for admonition. I'll not do that again.

Comment: @Woria No worries! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-3}{x-1}=2\implies \lim_{x\to1}[f(x)-3]=2 \lim_{x\to1}(x-1)=2\cdot0$$

As the limit exists, the numerator must $\to0$ as $x\to1$ as the denominator  $\to0$

Also, observe that $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=f'(1)$$